# Python if statement basic from file

Tags: python, csv, analysis

I have a CSV file containing wind speeds, their directions in degrees, and the date on which each datum was recorded.

I am trying to write an if statement so that if the direction is 180 and the date is within a certain month, then put those wind speeds into a new variable.

These are two attempts out of many others:

```
if ['Wind Direction'] == 180:
    if ['Wind Speed'].loc['2016-8-1':'2016-8-31']
        windS = ['Wind Speed']
        print(windS)
```

Another try that also didn't do anything:

```
for ['Wind Direction'] == 180:
    winddate = 'Date'
    if winddate == timedata[['Wind Speed']].loc['2016-8-1':'2016-8-31']:
        windspeedS = 'Wind Speed'
        print(windspeedS)
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: It would really help if you give a link to the CSV file

Comment: Is the code directly from your own solution, because you are missing `:`s at the end of your `if` statements.

Comment: perhaps check the type of windS to make sure it is an int, could be if int(windS) == 180

Comment: I'm not sure how to link it on here... I tried dropping the file here but it won't work.

Comment: it seems the code lacks understanding of basic Python syntax. Have you read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)? It is not so long, but quite comprehensive

Comment: @Dodo Not sure how to link something. It's a file on my computer! I tried to drop it in here but it didn't work.

Comment: @ReedJones it is a int!

Comment: Everything like `['Wind Direction']` must be `X['Wind Direction']`, where `X` is the name of the dataframe that you loaded from the file. (I assume that you _did_ load the CSV file as a DataFrame.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be fine with comparing the degree, but comparing the dates is what will need more tools. Python provides the library [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) that lets you create date objects to compare dates, which you can't really do with just strings. For example

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime("2016-8-1", "%Y-%m-%d")
date2 = datetime.strptime("2016-8-3", "%Y-%m-%d")
date3 = datetime.strptime("2016-8-30", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

First you give it the date as a string, then how the string is formatted, so that it will be parsed correctly. Now you can compare dates

```
date1 < date2 # returns True
date2 < date3 # returns True
date1 < date2 < date3 # returns True
```

If you only want data with dates in a certain month (as opposed to comparing two arbitrary dates), you can try something like this

```
date2.strftime("%B") == "August" # returns True
date2.month == 8 # returns True
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the datatime to just data?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? (note it's datetime, not datatime)